# Python datetime.fromisoformat requires colon in tzinfo?

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I am parsing date+time values in isoformat generated by another application, which look like this:

```
"2022-07-31T01:51:05-0400"
```

Note: The time zone info part is "-0400", without a colon.

But I can't see to use `datetime.fromisoformat` to do this:

```py
# This works fine (with a colon):

datetime.fromisoformat("2022-07-31T01:51:05-04:00")
datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 31, 1, 51, 05, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))

# But this does not (without a colon)

datetime.fromisoformat("2022-07-31T01:51:05-0400")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid isoformat string: '2000-10-20T01:02:03-0400'
```

The definition of valid ISO 8601 datetime formats explicitly include strings like "-0400":

> Time offsets from UTC
> The UTC offset is appended to the time in the same way that 'Z' was above, in the form ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh].
>
> Negative UTC offsets describe a time zone west of UTC±00:00, where the civil time is behind (or earlier) than UTC so the zone designator will look like "−03:00","−0300", or "−03".
>
> Positive UTC offsets describe a time zone at or east of UTC±00:00, where the civil time is the same as or ahead (or later) than UTC so the zone designator will look like "+02:00","+0200", or "+02".
>
> Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC

and the Python
[datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) says

> classmethod datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)
> Return a datetime corresponding to a date_string in any valid ISO 8601 format, with the following exceptions:
>
> Time zone offsets may have fractional seconds.
>
> The T separator may be replaced by any single unicode character.
>
> Ordinal dates are not currently supported.
>
> Fractional hours and minutes are not supported.

The non-colon form does not fall into any of the prohibited categories.

I know I can do something like this:

```py
datetime.strptime("2022-07-31T01:51:05-0400", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

where I explicitly indicate the datetime format, but the whole point of wanting to use `fromisoformat()` is so that I don't have to look up the format codes and spell it out explicitly.

Is there some way to do this and still use `fromisoformat`?

Comment: Which version of Python? Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat), up until 3.11 it only supported parsing what `.isoformat()` emitted, which includes the colon. In lower versions this is **explicitly** called out: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat.

Comment: `from dateutil import parser \n
date=parser.parse(date_iso8601_string)`. As @jonrsharpe mentioned, `fromisoformat` method is limited. dateutil is more robust

Answer (score 0):

You could do a workaround by making sure the colon is in the UTC offset portion of the string:

```
def fix_iso(s):
    pos = len("2022-07-31T01:51:05-0400") - 2 # take off end "00"
    if len(s) == pos:                 # missing minutes completely
        s += ":00"
    elif s[pos:pos+1] != ':':         # missing UTC offset colon
        s = f"{s[:pos]}:{s[pos:]}"
    return s
```

Just process the string with this before feeding to `fromisoformat()`. This takes care of missing colon and also when there are no minutes in the offset.

From what the OP and other commenters have stated, it sounds like Python is overclaiming standards compliance...

Comment: I think it's more the case that the OP is running Python3.10, but reading the latest docs (which are for 3.11).